# Dynamics CRM 2011 Bulk Delete Close Activities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I was trying to find a way to create a Bulk delete job for some Opportunity Close, Quote Close, & Incident Resolutions.  When I went to create the job I discovered that these particular entities are not available.  We can find and delete them in Advanced Find but at 250 at a time it would take far too long to delete them all this way.

Is there a way to Bulk Delete these Close Entities through the UI and if not is there any documentation that explains why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpportunityClose, QuoteClose and IncidentResolution are all Activity entities. You can create them, query, assign and delete them using the SDK, but in the UI there is only limited support for these entities. They do not show up in advanced find and bulk delete, because Microsoft decided not to flag them for these dialogs, probably to avoid confusion.

For bulk deletion you would need to develop a few lines of code yourself.
(Keep in mind these entities are Activities, hence the name of the primary key column is Always named 'activityid'.)